# When is multicollinearity a good thing or acceptable?

Tags: predictive-models, modeling, feature-selection, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

I was looking through a few scenarios where it might be okay to use variables that have high VIF [here](https://statisticalhorizons.com/multicollinearity). But most of [such discussions](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/what-are-the-effects-of-multicollinearity-and-when-can-i-ignore-them) and remedies I have seen use it in the context of linear regression models.

So the question that I have is- Is multicollinearity a bad thing for all models. More specifically, do I need to check for multicollinearity when building the following models

- Random Forest
- Decision Trees
- Boosting methods (GBTrees and XGBoost)
- SVM

Also, a second part I'd like to add is that- does it make a difference if I'm performing classification instead of regression. Do I need to interpret multicollinearity differently in these two cases?